# Structure of input and neural net to predict likelihood of multiple independent classes

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, feature-selection

For the problem I'm solving, the following is true:

- I'm trying to predict the probabilities for the input belonging to each of 12 classes.
- It's possible that the input belongs to none of the 12 classes, which means all 12 outputs (probabilities) would be low.
- The output probabilities should be independent. That is, if the likelihood of class 1 is 95%, the likelihood of class 2 could be >5% etc. In other words, I don't need the total probabilities to add up to 1 because some classes are similar. To be clear, in practice, each input can only belong to 1 class. What I'm referring to is the probabilities.

The way I'm currently approaching this is as follows:

- One hot encode the 12 output classes
- Loss function: Categorical crossentropy
- Final layer: Dense with 12 neurons and sigmoid activation

**Questions**

1. Does it make sense to have 1 model to predict membership of each of these 12 classes? Or does it make more sense to have independent models each of which predicts a probability just for one class? What's better?
2. Is it better to have 13 classes instead of 12 where the new one represents that the input doesn't belong to any class?

**Code**

```
test_fraction = 0.2
dropout_prob = 0.4
activation_function = 'relu'
loss_function = 'categorical_crossentropy'
opt = Adam()
verbose_level = 1
num_targets = 12
batch_size = 32
epochs = 75

X = np.array(keypoints)
labels = np.array(labels)
labels = np_utils.to_categorical(labels)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, labels, test_size=test_fraction, random_state=42)

# model training
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(180,)))
model.add(Dense(64, activation=activation_function))
model.add(Dense(128, activation=activation_function))
model.add(Dense(num_targets, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss=loss_function, optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=verbose_level,
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
model.save('../models/model.h5')
```

Comment: If each input can only belong to one class, then I don't understand how the probabilities can sum to greater than 1.  In practical terms, what method are you going to use to convert the output of your model into probabilities?  At any rate, if it's not possible for an input to belong to multiple classes then one model seems best to me.  I think you should have 13 classes to cover the 'none of the classes' case, but if all of your training instances belong to a class, then how are you going to train for the 13th case?

Answer (score 0):

This is called multi-label classification, and it can be easily implemented by making two changes in the model:

- Use a sigmoid activation at the output
- Use the binary_crossentropy loss which can handle multi-label classification.

And then just train your model.

Answer (score 0):

For start correct

```
model.add(Dense(num_targets, activation='sigmoid'))
```

to

```
model.add(Dense(num_targets, activation='softmax'))
```

`sigmoid activation` is used for binary classification not multiclass classification

To answer your questions i would say that

1. you don't need independent models (one model per class), one model for all is fine. One model per class could be from hardware recources point of view unprofitable.
2. Regarding your second question, to have 13 instead of 12 classes it depends from the problem you are dealing with. If you have data for this 13th  class you can train your model if that is what you want to do.